# Visual Studio 11 shims vs mocks

Tags: visual-studio-2012, shim

Just read about the new Stubs & Shims support in Visual Studio 11.

Stubs are clear to me, but Shims? Are they an alternative for Moles? Or can they be used to do mocking?

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, they aren't just the alternative to Moles, they are in fact the replacement. Shims can be used to isolate the code you're testing similarly to Moles.

From the [Microsoft Research page on Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/):

> The Fakes Framework in Visual Studio 2012 is the next generation of Moles & Stubs. Fakes is different from Moles, however, so moving from Moles to Fakes will require some modifications to your code. The Moles framework will not be supported in Visual Studio 2012.